# PTV independent current reference without any golden voltage reference

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-source

I'm familiar with building current references using Mosfets. But they are generally dependent on one of the corners (either Process,Voltage,Temperature). I haven't been able to remove the dependence on all the three parameters together. Please suggest me if it's possible to build one such without using BJT's/ bandgaps/ any external source references.

Comment: Have you ever used an op-amp?

Comment: Yes, but I would be interested in knowing an approach using mosfets (like the standard current mirroring based topologies) than system level designing.

Comment: What makes you think this can be done without specs on PVT and output tolerance.  ( or even with specs)

Comment: That's a bit of a holy grail..

Comment: YEs it is the reason why stable references were designed in chips, not possible with your limitations.

Comment: Hi @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I know. I haven't come across any topology which allows me to make it independent of PVT at once. Regarding the specs, it would be Process-Fast, slow. Voltage= 1.8V+/-10%. Temp= -25C to 110C. A 15% tolerance is very good if possible.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I was only curious if PVT independent circuits are possible without good bandgaps, etc after seeing this [paper](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2014/IMECS2014_pp690-694.pdf) which claims PVT independence.

Comment: Building with 22nm Intel process  with "typical" tight controls  may be accurate as reported, but not for discrete parts.